# Defining Rules in Scrapy while accessing through flask

Tags: python, flask, scrapy

I am running scrapy spider using flask and crochet. In this I am using Rule Link extractor for defining the rules. In the rule, I am setting `allow_domains` which is passed from flask application.

**spider.py**

```
class myCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'symphony'
    base_url=''
    start_urls = []
    allowed_domains = ''

    def __init__(self, category='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.base_url = category
        self.allowed_domains = ['.'.join(urlparse(self.base_url).netloc.split('.')[-2:])]
        self.start_urls.append(self.base_url)
        print(f"Base url is {self.base_url} and allowed domain is {self.allowed_domains}")      

    custom_settings = {
        # in order to reduce the risk of getting blocked
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {'sitescrapper.sitescrapper.middlewares.RotateUserAgentMiddleware': 400, },
        'COOKIES_ENABLED': False,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 6,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 2,
        # Duplicates pipeline
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'sitescrapper.sitescrapper.pipelines.DuplicatesPipeline': 300},

        # In order to create a CSV file:
        'FEEDS': {'csv_file.csv': {'format': 'csv'}}
    }

    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(allow_domains='.'.join(urlparse(self.base_url).netloc.split('.')[-2:])),
            process_links=process_links,
            callback='parse_item',
            follow=True
        ),
    )
```

Here I gave `LinkExtractor(allow_domains='.'.join(urlparse(self.base_url).netloc.split('.')[-2:]))`. But `self` is not defined there which throws an error. So how can I assign the value of expression `'.'.join(urlparse(self.base_url).netloc.split('.')[-2:])` to the variable `allow_domains` [which is also same as `self.allowed_domains`] Or else is there any better method to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that CrawlSpider constructor (**init**) is also handling the rules parameter, so if we need to assign them, we'll have to do it before calling the default constructor.

```
class myCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'symphony'
    rotate_user_agent = True
    base_url=''
    start_urls = []
    allowed_domains = ''

    def __init__(self, category='', **kwargs):
        self.base_url = category
        self.allowed_domains = ['.'.join(urlparse(self.base_url).netloc.split('.')[-2:])]
        self.start_urls.append(self.base_url)
        print(f"Base url is {self.base_url} and allowed domain is {self.allowed_domains}")  

        self.rules = (
            Rule(
                LinkExtractor(allow_domains=self.allowed_domains),
                process_links=process_links,
                callback='parse_item',
                follow=True
            ),
        )   
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    custom_settings = {
            # in order to reduce the risk of getting blocked
            'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {'sitescrapper.sitescrapper.middlewares.RotateUserAgentMiddleware': 400, },
            'COOKIES_ENABLED': False,
            'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 6,
            'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 2,

            # Duplicates pipeline
            'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'sitescrapper.sitescrapper.pipelines.DuplicatesPipeline': 300},

            # In order to create a CSV file:
            'FEEDS': {'csv_file.csv': {'format': 'csv'}}
        }
```